# macdeployqt breaking app

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, macdeployqt

I've installed Qt creator 5.11.0,

then i changed some things i needed to change on my old project and when i try to build it, it works as intended, but after using macdeployqt, my app can't load.

So, when i run macdeployqt like this :

```
./macdeployqt /Users/`MY_USERNAME`/Downloads/build-`MY_PROJECT_NAME`-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_clang_64bit-Release/`MY_PROJECT_NAME`.app -qmldir=/Users/`MY_USERNAME`/Downloads/build-`MY_PROJECT_NAME`-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_clang_64bit-Release/ -dmg -verbose=3
```

It all finishes 'successfully', but my app won't load.
If i try to run it from QtCreator, it outputs this

```
qrc:/main.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:4 module "QtGraphicalEffects" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:4 module "QtGraphicalEffects" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:4 module "QtGraphicalEffects" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:4 module "QtGraphicalEffects" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed

qrc:/main.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-qmldir` option is the path to your QML files in the *source directory* of your app. Try to run it like this (assuming that the argument to `-qmldir` is the path to your app's source directory):

```
./macdeployqt \
    /Users/`MY_USERNAME`/Downloads/build-`MY_PROJECT_NAME`-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_clang_64bit-Release/`MY_PROJECT_NAME`.app \
    -qmldir=/Users/`MY_USERNAME`/Downloads/`MY_PROJECT_NAME`/ \
    -dmg -verbose=3
```

Otherwise, the tool will search for QML files in the build directory, where it will find none and hence consequentially not include any of the QML modules.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your time. Unfortunately, I was not able to do anything with 5.11.0 Qt version. After uninstalling, and installing 5.10.0 version, everything worked like charm.

Comment: Worked with 5.11 for me 